# Unable to install mac Big Sur beta 11.0.1 in Macbook pro 2020

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-update, big-sur

'I am unable to install `Big Sur beta 11.0.1`. It is downloading fully from the update screen and showing 15 minutes remaining for the installation process. Then the below screen is coming.

[image]

**I'm continuously getting this since last 5 times. No success in the update.**

Is there any way to fix this? Any help could be appreciated

Comment: Try rebooting all your network devices; router, wifi, ethernet hubs & Mac. Try again. It's probably [badly] cached somewhere on the way to you so you're trying to fetch the exact same wrong data every time -  this might just shake it loose.

Comment: @Tetsujin, No success. I tried in safe mode too. Still the same error

Comment: It may be that the cached update is still on your Mac and causing this issue, which is the opposite of what a cache is supposed to do. See if you have a big file or files in /Library/Updates that could be the Big Sur cache and delete it.

Comment: @SteveChambers, Thanks for the suggestion. I turnd off the filevault and updated the OS from terminal. It is working fine now

Comment: Great you could solve the issue and update the OS. Any chance you would be willing to rewrite your comment into a answer? That could help others with a similar issue. You can then mark your answer as accepted (that will mark your question as solved) and collect the reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this finally.

1. I turned off the file vault
2. Run the update from the terminal using the command
   `softwareupdate --install "macOS Big Sur Release Candidate 2-20B28"`